# How to add a "signature" field to a list?

Tags: list, custom-list

I have simple custom SharePoint list with 20 fields. Three of the fields are dropdown lists for three separate approvers to update the record with "approve" or "reject."  I would like to implement a way to place the user's login name next to the dropdown list they update. This way we know that the approval is valid. Any guidance on this issue would be appreciated.

Here is an example:

```
Field A approver: [dropdown list]  (USER.1)
Field B approver: [dropdown list]  (USER.2)
Field C approver: [dropdown list]  (USER.3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably won' be able to do this, however, You could consider a workflow to populate a field with the approval and the last person to modify it so that would give you the same kind of functionality without having to custom code something.

Comment: thanks for your input, can you elaborate a little more on mini-markdown formatting. thanks.

Comment: You could still create a field that has the drop-down like before, only you would also create a field that is a text field. Create a workflow that fires on edit and combines the text of the drop-down field and the name of the person who modified the form and uses this data to populate the text field. That way it will contain the result and who made the change.

Comment: just the solution i was looking for. your advice worked like a charm. i set up a spd workflow, added some if conditions, stored the modified username into a string, and updated at text field with the stored string. thanks!

Comment: turns out this solution is difficult to implement for more than one drop down approval field and or more than one approval type (approve, reject) :/  I am using [Wait for field to equal value] then [store dynamic string in variable] then [update item in list]

Comment: You could just have the workflow fire on edit and use a condition If <field 1> is not blank and <field 1+username field> is blank then..., If <field 2> is not blank and <field 2 +username field> is not blank then...

Comment: thanks. i get this working but for some reason, when edit the item for the first time, i get a generic message saying "an unexpected error has occurred". after the first edit everything works perfectly. i put in a new question regarding the issue. "get error page on first attempt to edit item"

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality will require some custom coding. (or you can use @Lori's solutions if custom work is not an option)

Here are a couple of links that can get you started on creating custom web parts:

- http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/create-a-custom-web-part-for-sharepoint-2010/
- http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/02/15/intro-to-sharepoint-2010-development-how-to-build-and-deploy-a-web-part.aspx

Comment: thanks but i would have to build a custom field type, not a webpart :/ i forgot to mention that i'm using 2007.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had to do this, I created a field for each approver and used a workflow to populate them.

If Status 1 is not null and Status 1 User is null, populate the Status 1 User with the value of the modified by and modified columns to get the user and date/time that the field was updated. Repeat the process for the other two fields.

In this scenario, I'd also use some jQuery to hide the user fields from the forms so that nobody inputs anything into them except for the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider InfoPath 2010 Signature Line Control. Very good read below. Since you can build a InfoPath form for an existing SharePoint list in 2010, it should be easy to upgrade to InfoPath.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/digital-signatures-in-infopath-2010-HA010381868.aspx